# Entity Framework does not embed metadata into dll

Tags: c#, entity-framework, msbuild, teamcity, embedded-resource

### What I'm trying to do

I currently have a project file that contains a single EF 5 Model with the .edmx configured to embed the metadata into the output assembly.

If I run a local package via Visual Studio 2012, the produced assemblies contain the correct resources. Manually running package through MSBuild also correctly embeds the resources in the assembly:

```
msbuild web.csproj /t:Package /p:Configuration=Release
```

When I manually inspect the assembly generated by Visual Studio *or* by the MSBuild package step with [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), I can confirm that the package contains the .csdl, .ssdl and .msl resources.

### The actual problem

I have on hand a build server that is running Microsoft Windows Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2012. If I manually run MSBuild via the Visual Studio 2012 Command Prompt, using the same exact command line as above, then an assembly is generated that does *not* contain the resources embedded.

Why are my EF metadata files not being embedded when I perform automated packages via MSBuild?

### Simple Self Contained Correct Example

A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates the workaround may be found [here](http://db.tt/Q9ZvgQYX). The example contains the exact steps required to reproduce the error in the `readme.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, on Windows 8 + VS2012 installed, I was able to generate package using Package.bat and all generated assemblies are contain the all EF metadata files.
In the Readme.txt you are mention the MSDeploy

> 4) Run MSDeploy /t:package on the project

From your question looks like you have issues with MSBuild.
Could you verify that you don't have old TestEntityEdmx.Hackaround.dll sitting in the TestEntityEdmx\obj\Release... folder when you run build.

Comment: In my post, I meant (which the old one didn't reflect) that the `SSCCE` was an example of the `workaround`. The `readme.txt` contained the actual instructions to produce the actual flaw. I re-ran the *exact* files I've had on my hard drive (after cleaning all `bin`, `obj`) and it appears to embed properly. It seems like they may have fixed this in the recent VS tools update.